# How to loop this code, for every 50 points a student scored, 1 star is added

Tags: python

Apologize in advance, but I am a beginner in python and still learning. And I got this problem, for every 50 points the student earn while playing, 1 star will be added on their information. But I cannot seem to do it, here's my code;

```
class points:
    def __init__ (self, studentname, points, star):
        self.studentname = studentname
        self.points = points
        self.star = star

    def play (self, totalpoints):
        self.points += totalpoints

        #every time the students score 50, they will have plus 1 star
        if self.points == 50:
            self.star += 1

    def displayInfo (self):
        print (self.studentname)
        print(self.points)
        print(self.star)

student1 = points("Ana", 0, 0)
student2 = points("Sandra", 0, 0)

student1.displayInfo()
student2.displayInfo() #will display their information before playing

student1.play(10)
student2.play(5)
student1.play(20)
student2.play(10)
student1.play(30)
student2.play(30)
student1.play(10)
student2.play(5)
student1.play(20)
student2.play(10)
student1.play(30)
student2.play(30)

student1.displayInfo()
student2.displayInfo() #will display their information after playing
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only adding one star when a student reaches **exactly** 50 points and never again. What you could do inside your `play()` method is update the number of stars a player has each time you add points, like so:

```
def play(self, totalpoints):
    self.points += totalpoints
    self.star = self.points // 50
```

This uses [Python's `floordiv` operator (`//`)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)